# How to inject a service into Blazor?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I'm having trouble trying to inject some services into the client project. In the `Program.cs` file I have the following:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();

            ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        }


        public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IMetamaskInterop, MetamaskBlazorInterop>();
            services.AddSingleton<MetamaskService>();
            services.AddSingleton<MetamaskInterceptor>();
        }
    }
```

In a new component I try to inject these services as follows:

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime;
@inject MetamaskService metamaskService;
@inject MetamaskInterceptor metamaskInterceptor;
```

But doing this is giving me an error and it is the following:

[image]

I appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: Please include the relevant part of the error directly in your question as text (not just as an image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't introduce a new static method named `ConfigureServices` into the `Program` class. This is not the reason for the exception thrown, but it is greatly misleading as `ConfigureServices` is the name of a method defined in the Startup class (used in the past in WebAssembly Blazor, and then removed...).

Sometimes, you may need a second method for conditional configuration, but don't name it `ConfigureServices`. In the current instance, you don't need a second method. Just do it as it is done below.

When you use a second method, you mustn't run
`await builder.Build().RunAsync();` as this code build and execute your app, rendering it too late to add more services to the service collection. Just pass the IServiceCollection object to the second method, and when it returns build and run your app.

Here's the updated version of your code:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
            builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

            builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
            
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMetamaskInterop, MetamaskBlazorInterop>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MetamaskService>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MetamaskInterceptor>();

            await builder.Build().RunAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You are configuring the services after you start you app.

Add `ConfigureServices(builder.Services);` before `await builder.Build().RunAsync();`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
        builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

        builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

        // configure services before running the app
        ConfigureServices(builder.Services);

        await builder.Build().RunAsync();

    }


    public static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton<IMetamaskInterop, MetamaskBlazorInterop>();
        services.AddSingleton<MetamaskService>();
        services.AddSingleton<MetamaskInterceptor>();
    }
}
```